# detail or detailing

Tags: nouns, gerunds, late-modern-english

In the following extract from *Frankenstein*, which of the two possibilities do you think makes more sense?

> and although I loved him with a mixture of affection and reverence that knew no bounds, yet I could never persuade myself to confide in him that event which was so often present to my recollection, but which I feared the **detail**/**detailing** to another would only impress more deeply.

Comment: If it is an extract, there is no choice.

Answer (score 0):

The word is "detail" since that is what is in the published version.

To understand this you need to look at obselete meanings of detail (as is often the case if you choose to read 200 year old books.

> detail: a narrative that relates to minute points of focusses on particulars (paraphrased from [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/detail#Noun))

And read this with an understanding of grammar that also is 200 years old.

Comment: Where did you find the quoted definition?